# Clase Date sin milisegundos en formato de fecha en Java

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime

En estos momentos estoy trabajando en una aplicación que graba en una base de datos SQLServer una serie de datos de productos, y lo está haciendo de esta manera:

```java
Date fecha = new Date();
.
.
CLASEOBJETO.setFecha(fecha);
.
.
```

El caso es que al generar el Date, e insertarlo en la base de datos, me inserta "2024-01-29 11:46:27.907", incluidos los milisegundos.

El problema viene porque ese dato tiene que leerlo otra aplicación que no soporta los milisegundos, con lo cual lo que debería grabar es "2024-01-29 11:46:27" o en su defecto "2024-01-29 11:46:27.000".

He estado mirando los formatos de Date, pero no he encontrado la manera. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Estás usando `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @padaleiana y si le respondemos para Date y time?

Answer (score 1):

La librería java.time.LocalDateTime te ayuda a manejar de manera más facil el tema de las fechas, formateandolo de esta manera. además tu propiedad Fecha de tu clase objeto deberias modificarlo a un String.

```
   //Probamos con la hora del sistema
   LocalDateTime fechaActual = LocalDateTime.now();

   //Formateamos la fecha para tener el formato deseado
   String fechaString = fechaActual.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```

y asi deberias obtener la fecha junto a la hora.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo solucione así:

```
Calendar miCal = Calendar.getInstance();                       
Date fechaNueva = new Date();                     
miCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
fechaNueva = new Date(miCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Y posteriormente ya insertando.

Comment: Recuerda que en lugar de agradecer textualmente, puedes votar a favor de las respuestas que consideres más útiles. Por otra parte, considera aceptar la respuesta que entre todas te ha sido más útil.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes quitar dejar en cero los milisegundos de un objeto `Date` simplemente dividiéndolo por mil y volviéndolo a multiplicar por mil

```
Date fecha = new Date();
fecha.setTime((fecha.getTime() / 1000) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que puedas manejar la **precisión del campo datetime** desde la base de datos, estableciendo que la precisión sea solamente hasta los segundos, para ello ejecuta el siguiente comando desde tu gestor de base de datos:

```
alter table Tabla alter column campo datetime2(0);
```

**Tabla** es el nombre de la tabla que contiene el campo que deseas modificar y **campo** es el nombre del campo que deseas modificar. **datetime2(0)** es el nuevo tipo de datos que deseas asignar al campo, lo que significa que se almacenará con una precisión de segundos.

Answer (score -1):

```
String fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").format("2024-01-29 11:46:27.907");
```

prueba con esto

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y también [CHATGPT y similares están prohibidos en el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: y eso que hace?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/403315)

Answer (score -1):

En lo personal siempre me gusta tener clases y metodo utilitarios con los cuales pueda obtener rapidamente lo que quiera y no hacerlo citando muy seguido codigo sobre la marcha ya que si unformato cambia, tendria que buscar en todo el proyecto las veces que se usa ese formato.

te felicito por que vaz en la direccion correcta hacia la estandarizacion de proyectos y del codigo.

***yo haria lo siguiente:*** con [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date fecha = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String fechaFormateada = formatter.format(fecha);
        System.out.println("Fecha formateada sin milisegundos: " + fechaFormateada);
        
        // Aquí insertarías la fechaFormateada en tu base de datos

    }
}
```

Crea un objeto SimpleDateFormat con el formato `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, que representa `año-mes-día hora:minuto:segundo`. Luego, utiliza este formato para formatear la fecha y obtener una cadena sin milisegundos.

**Nota:** es importante mencionar que la clase `Date` está obsoleta y se recomienda utilizar las clases del paquete `java.time` introducidas en `Java 8` para un mejor manejo de fechas y tiempos. Sin embargo, si estás limitado a usar Date, este enfoque funciona correctamente.

***La Alternativa con:*** [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime fechaHora = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String fechaFormateada = fechaHora.format(formatter);
        System.out.println("Fecha formateada sin milisegundos: " + fechaFormateada);
        
        // Aquí insertarías la fechaFormateada en tu base de datos

    }
}
```

Veras que estoy creando un objeto `LocalDateTime` utilizando el método `now()` para obtener la fecha y hora actual. Luego, se define un formateador de fecha y hora utilizando el patrón "`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. Se formatea la fecha y hora utilizando este formateador, lo que resulta en una cadena sin milisegundos.